# how to know what function inside the .so library file and how to link the specific binary code into your code?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

There are shared libraries in the linux. For example, libcap.so.2.24.

I knew when I write c code, when I write something like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  printf("hello world\n");
  return 0;
}
```

the gcc compile will automatic include the printf function from the library and generate the objection file.

My question is

1. is there other ways to get the binary code for printf besides to use compile?
2. when the compile include the printf in the objection file, does it include the whole library libcap.so.2.24 or just the part related to printf function? I am guess it only includes the part related to printf function, if so, how does the compile do it?
3. can I include the function from the library manually without using the compiler?

Comment: Simliar problem: https://superuser.com/questions/161722/how-to-list-imported-symbols-in-elf-executable

Answer (score 0):

```
1) The compiler only includes the header files, not the library itself
2) During linking the library is bound to the executable.
   How this happens depends if static or dynamic linking is used
3) It is possible to bind a library at runtime with the dlopen library function
   and then use dlsym to get a function pointer.
   The dlopen man page has a very nice example
```